# Horizontal and vertical centering above a sticky footer in CSS

Tags: html, css, center, footer, centering

Given a sticky footer such as that on Ryan Fait's site with a fixed pixel height, is it possible to center, both horizontally and vertically, variable-size content in the space above this footer?

Comment: a lttle more info please? a link to the example would be good. and if this page is what you want, inspect the code there. I am not sure if it is a sticky footer and not just a footer, and why would you want to centre a footer vertically? Or is it the content above the footer you want to centre?

Comment: The footer I mean is here:
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

He centres the page above the footer horizontally, but not vertically. I essentially want to add vertical centring, between the page top and the footer.

Comment: ..so you a´have a wrap div that contains everything, footer included. Then you have a div that contains whatever you want centered vertically, minus the footer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No answers for variable-size content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [Bobby van der Sluis's article on Footers at *A List Apart*](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/footers/).

[Example #7](http://www.alistapart.com/d/footers/footer_variation1.html) at the end of his article shows a vertically centered block. It **does** rely on scripting, but it is truly minimal.

`edit` You can also use a single-cell table to accomplish vertical centering. Incorporating it with Ryan Fait's sticky footer would give you something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">        

    /* Original Sticky Footer: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ */

    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        }

    #footer {
        margin-top: -150px;
        height: 150px;
        }

    #footer {
        background: #bbd;
        }

    .block {
        width: 300px;
        padding: 20px;
        background: yellow;
        margin: 0 auto 150px; /* height of #footer */
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tr><td>

        <div class="block">
            <h1>Vertically Centered!</h1>
            <p>This block will remain centered. Just needs that one table cell wrapping.</p>
        </div>

    </td></tr>
</table>

<div id="footer">Footer Content here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I always feel dirty using tables, but I suppose that's how it's gotta be for something like this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

well, then you could set this for the vertical align of content:

```
.verticalalign{
width:270px;
height:150px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-75px 0 0 -135px;
```

}

Comment: The issue being that I'm not going to know the size of the content to specify absolute values like that, hence the problem.