# CSS, Top, Bottom Div as well as centered horizontal Div

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="site_wrapper">
<div id="top"><?=$top?></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="login_wrapper">
<?=$content?>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><?=$footer?></div>
</div>
```

Where

```
$top should be drawn on the very top of the page.  
$content should be centered both vertically and horizontally of the page.  
$footer should be drawn on the very bottom of the page.
```

I do not want either of the divs to follow the view, I found two solutions for the problems one by one, but none to combine them, seeing as they both had the height element in css. So first I guess if it even is possible (which I guess it is) second is then of course, how?

Edit: Pretty much like this side, the top bar should always be on the top, that one is fairly straight forward.

Then the #login_wrapper should always be centered in the site with a fixed height.

Last the footer should always be on the bottom (it should be pushed not stickied), because in this case #login_wrapper wont fill out the site.

The #top and #footer both have fixed heights as well.

Edit2: Fixed some clarifications for the problem.

Found solution from this site [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909587/horizontal-and-vertical-centering-above-a-sticky-footer-in-css
Thanks anyway!

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909587/horizontal-and-vertical-centering-above-a-sticky-footer-in-css>

There I found what I was looking for. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, try with this css

```
#site_wrapper
{
position: relative;
}

#top
{
position: relative;
top: 0px;
}

#footer
{
position: relative;
bottom: 0px;
}

#wrapper
{
position:relative;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
}

#login_wrapper
{
/* add some height */
}
```

Comment: From digging a bit the code the code should look something like this [link](http://pastebin.com/Jwpzpcx7) But the problem is that the center wrapper code does not work with the push the footer div to the bottom. I do not want the divs to be sticky on the screen.